# Restrict access to folder, subfolder and files - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can i restrict the access for a specific domain with following condition:

```
- /uploads -> not allowed, redirect to xxx.com
- /uploads/application_files -> not allowed, redirect to xxx.com
- /uploads/application_files/2020 -> not allowed, redirect to xxx.com
- /uploads/application_files/2020/03 -> not allowed, redirect to xxx.com
- /uploads/application_files/2020/03/test.pdf -> not allowed, redirect to xxx.com
```

These files shouldn't be reachable from this domain: yyy.com

Can you guys give me a hint?

Comment: Best is to have that ``upload`` folder _outside_ your http hosts ``DOCUMENT_ROOT`` so that it cannot be accessed directly at all. Since the upload is controlled by some form of application logic on your side (I assume) the same is possible for usage or download of files stored there.

Comment: "from this domain: `yyy.com`" - you presumably mean "at" this domain? (As opposed to traffic that is coming "from" this domain?!) `yyy.com` is presumably different to `xxx.com`? But why "redirect"? Why not simply "block" access (and perhaps give a meaningful message to users)?